# MongoDB server doesn’t close when pressing Ctrl+C after changing the system date to a date in the past

Tags: windows-7, windows, mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB 3.4.4.

I run MongoDB using the `mongo_start` batch file. I normally close the shell that appears using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and it works most of the time. But when I roll back the system date to a previous one (ex. change system date to yesterday's date) while the MongoDB server is up, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> stops working (i.e. the shell does not close).

It seems like this was caused by the `--journal` parameter because when I changed it to no journal, I was able to close the shell with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> even after I changed the system date to a previous date. But after checking the same case with an older MongoDB server (which also has the `--journal` parameter), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> closed the shell after I changed system date to previous date.

I would like to know what exactly caused the shell to not close with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> after I changed the system date to an older date. Thanks!

Comment: Well, here’s a crazy question: Why are you changing the date to a date in the past? Testing some date-based logic?

Comment: Yep. I tried a C# code that uses the SystemEvents.TimeChanged. I wanted to try closing the MongoDB shell "automatically" when the user changes the system date.

Comment: By the way, on closing it automatically, I wanted to use the execution of ctrl+c. I do know that I can use Process.kill() instead, but I'm curious about what causes ctrl+c to not close the MongoDB shell when I rollback the system date.

Answer (score 1):

Given your MongoDB server version of 3.4.4 and the current problem description (changing the system clock backwards), I expect that upgrading to MongoDB 3.4.6 or later will resolve this issue. The latest production release in that series is currently 3.4.19 (January, 28  2019), and there have been many [bug fixes and stability improvements](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-changelog/) since 3.4.4 was released (April 21, 2017).

There were a few issues related to system clocks jumping backward which would cause WiredTiger stalls or hangs during [checkpoints](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger-checkpoints) (for example, see [WT-3331](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-3331) and [WT-3327](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-3327) in the MongoDB issue tracker). These were addressed in the MongoDB 3.4.6 release.

This is also mentioned under the [Clock Synchronization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#clock-synchronization) section of the MongoDB production notes:

> Use NTP to synchronize the clocks on all components of your MongoDB deployment. Replica sets and sharded clusters running MongoDB 3.4.5 or earlier with the WiredTiger storage engine may experience checkpoint hangs on systems with unreliable clocks.

```
It seems like this was caused by the --journal parameter
```

The shutdown sequence involves a checkpoint to make journaled writes durable in the data files. If you have disabled journalling (which is strongly not recommended for production environments), you would instead be triggering checkpoints on each write. I expect that disabling the journal would have made it less likely for your server to have a checkpoint including data that was written before the clock went backwards, although you could perhaps still run into issues in 3.4.4 if the system clock changes concurrently with writes.